# Active error 438 when retrieving shape value with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This question is a follow up to my 2 previous questions ([Retrieving name and location of specific Shapes from worksheet with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834046/retrieving-name-and-location-of-specific-shapes-from-worksheet-with-vba) and [Retrieving information of OLEObjects from Workbook with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53830793/retrieving-information-of-oleobjects-from-workbook-with-vba))

**Scenario:** I am trying to retrieve data from worksheet, including raw data and shapes (mostly checkboxes). I am using the following code to retrieve the checkboxes:

```
Sub CheckboxLoop17()

Dim cb As Shape
Dim i As Long

i = 1

'Loop through Checkboxes
  For Each cb In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(i, 1).Value = cb.ControlFormat.Value
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(i, 2).Value = cb.Name
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(i, 3).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Address
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(i, 4).Value = cb.Type
    i = i + 1
  Next cb

End Sub
```

When run, the code yields the Active error 438 in the line:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(i, 1).Value = cb.ControlFormat.Value
```

Where I want to get any type of value representation from the checkbox (true/false, yes/no, 1/0...)

**Question:** Why is this error happening? How to fix this?

Comment: It is likely happening because you are looping through all shapes and one of the shapes is not a control. *'Note If the shape isn't a control, the ControlFormat property fails.'*

Comment: @user10798192 Most probably. Is there any other way to retrieve the value of the shape directly?

Comment: Are you just interested in the Checkboxes?

Comment: @TinMan My sheet has checkboxes shapes only, but some are Form and some are ActiveX.

Comment: It might be better to use `Sheets("Sheet1")` to reference the correct sheet by tab name.  `Sheets(1)` references the first sheet in tab order which can be rearranged by the user (so can the tab name).... maybe better to use the sheet codename - `...In Sheet1.Shapes`.  The codename is the sheet name _not_ in brackets in the VBE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Sub CheckboxLoop17()

    Dim cb As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, shpWs As Worksheet

    Set shpWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
    i = 1

    'Loop through Checkboxes
    With Ws
      For Each cb In shpWs.Shapes

        If cb.Type = msoFormControl Then
            If cb.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Value = cb.ControlFormat.Value
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = cb.Name
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Address
                .Cells(i, 4).Value = cb.Type
            End If
        ElseIf cb.Type = 12 Then
            s = cb.OLEFormat.progID
            If s = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Value = cb.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = cb.Name
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = cb.BottomRightCell.Address
                .Cells(i, 4).Value = cb.Type
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
      Next cb
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ooh, `Shape.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value` - I've never realised you needed that second `.Object`, and have always resorted to `Worksheet.OLEObjects(Shape.Name).Object.Value` instead.  So much code I can tidy up now >_<'

Answer (score 2):

Excel wraps each ActiveX object in an OLEObject control, which is then wrapped in a Shape object.

When iterating over the `Worksheets().Shapes` you will need to reference the `Shape..Object.Object.Value`

> ```
> ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(i, 1).Value = cb.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value
> ```

It would be more direct to loop over the `Worksheets().OLEObjects` collection.

```
Sub CheckboxLoop17_OLEObjects()
    Dim ctrl As OLEObject
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1

    'Loop through Checkboxes
    For Each ctrl In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).OLEObjects
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(i, 1).Value = ctrl.Object.Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(i, 2).Value = ctrl.Name
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(i, 3).Value = ctrl.BottomRightCell.Address
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(i, 4).Value = ctrl.progID
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

If you have both Form and ActiveX controls then you will need to test what type you are working with.

```
Sub MixedFormsAndActiveX()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim i As Long
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes
        i = i + 1
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4)
            If sh.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Value = sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value
                .Cells(i, 4).Value = "ActiveX Control: " & TypeName(sh.OLEFormat.Object.Object)
            ElseIf sh.Type = msoFormControl Then
                .Cells(i, 1).Value = sh.ControlFormat.Value
                .Cells(i, 4).Value = "Forms Control: " & TypeName(sh.ControlFormat)
            End If
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = sh.Name
            .Cells(i, 3).Value = sh.BottomRightCell.Address
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This does it for the ActiveX, but then it leaves out the Form Control. I am trying to do both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `FormControlType` property. I played around with your example and using intellisense found that property. Looking at the MS description they had the following example:

```
For Each s In Worksheets(1).Shapes
    If s.Type = msoFormControl Then
        If s.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then _
            s.ControlFormat.Value = False
    End If
Next
```

As noted by other commentors, the error that pops up is due to the code encountering shape objects which do not have the properties you are asking for. Then an error is produced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Problem is, this will only read the Checkboxes that are from Form Control, and it will ignore the ones from ActiveX.

Comment: @DGMS89 Use `Shape.Type` to get the [MsoShapeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype) first: `msoFormControl` for a Form Control, or `msoOLEControlObject` for an OLE Control Object.

Comment: @Chronocidal I did that to get both, but from there, there is the same error when trying to retrieve the value.

Comment: @DGMS89 Only a Shape of Type `msoFormControl` will have a `ControlFormat`.  For a Shape of `msoOLEControlObject`, the best I can do is `s.Parent.OLEObjects(s.Name).Object.Value` - can anyone refine that further?